# Why is the quadratic covariation of two independent brownian motions zero?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, quadratic-variation

In my notes there is a remark saying that if $B$ and $B'$ are independent Brownian motions, then $\langle B,B'\rangle = 0$.

I know the following properties of quadratic covariation:

1. $\langle M, N \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\Bigl(\langle M+N, M+N \rangle - \langle M, M\rangle - \langle N,N \rangle \Bigr)$
2. The process $\langle M, N \rangle$ is the unique finite variation processes such that $(M_tN_t - \langle M,N \rangle_t)$ is a continuous local martingale.
3. $\langle M,N \rangle_t = \lim_{||\pi_n|| \rightarrow 0} \sum_{t_i \in \pi_n}(M_{t_{i+1}} - M_{t_i})(N_{t_{i+1}} - N_{t_i})$, where the limit is in probability.

I also know that the quadratic variation of a Brownian motion $\langle B, B \rangle_t = t$.

I feel like the result is a very basic combination of these properties but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: This probably follows most directly from the polarisation identity (1). Note that, if $B,B'$ are independent Brownian motions, then $(B_t+B'_t)_{t \geq 0} \overset{d}{=} (B_{2t})_{t \geq 0}$ as processes. So $\langle B + B', B+B' \rangle_t = 2t = \langle B,B\rangle_t + \langle B' + B' \rangle_t$.

Comment: @Julius Thank you very much!